# What do you love about this site?

Tags: discussion

I thought it would be helpful to have a meta question where we could keep track of what is really great about Hermeneutics.SE. So: **What do you love about this site?**

Go ahead and list each item as a separate answer. Vote up if you "strongly agree," down if you "strongly disagree" and leave it alone if you're undecided.

The top-voted answers here can guide us in ensuring we are protecting and encouraging the right things as we discuss the scope of the site in other meta questions.

---

Also, see the follow-up to this question: [What do you hate about this site?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/608/529)

Comment: Something about that last sentence reminded me of Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Answer (score -2):

### One site with many different members

> For just as we have many members in one body and all the members do not have the same function, so we, who are many, are one body in Christ, and individually members one of another, since we have gifts that differ according to the grace given to us [***-Jas 3.1's highly speculative translation of Romans 12:4-6***](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5323/529)*****

I looked at the top users on this site the other day and smiled.

[image]

I love how each active user on this site has their own area of expertise, and how we can all come together and learn from one another's strengths. Whatever we do with this site, let's strive to preserve the diversity of expertise.

---

**If you don't like my translation, go answer the question it is linked to... that's what you're here for!*

Comment: @GoneQuiet Haha... consider it idiosyncratic flavor. (Actually, the verse doesn't even apply from a Christian perspective... I just included it to convey the gist of what I was about to describe; one site with many vari-skilled members.)