# What do you hate about this site?

Tags: discussion

As a follow up of [What do you love about this site?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/529), I thought it would be helpful to have a meta question where we could keep track of what we would desperately like to see improved on Hermeneutics.SE. So: **What do you "hate" about this site?**

Go ahead and list each item as a separate answer. Vote up if you "strongly agree," down if you "strongly disagree" and leave it alone if you're undecided.

The top-voted answers here can guide us in ensuring we are addressing and discouraging the right things as we discuss the scope of the site in other meta questions.

Answer (score 5):

### I wish we had more...

This is probably my favorite site on the entire internet... I just wish we had more...

- More experts on hand to answer tough questions
- More expert Q&A traffic in general... some days there's *nothing* going on here, which is always disappointing if I'm looking for something interesting to read
- More people voting... there's nothing like spending half a day on a post only to find out months later you only got 2 votes on it... lol
- More ***non-*** experts asking questions... we're pretty good at driving away newbies sometimes

I'm sure we would all like to see "more," and it's not easy to figure out how to do that, but as we make decisions for this site, I think we should definitely keep in mind our end goal of making this site **more** than it is today.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "non-expert" and what you mean by "common sense within the Jewish and Christian communities". A non-expert might come here and ask a question under the influence that there is no separation between religion and scripture. Although religion may be based on scripture, that is not always the case; sometimes, a bit of "traditional interpretation" makes religion religion.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't understand how your comment relates to my post. I didn't mention "common sense within the Jewish and Christian communities" or "separation between religion and scripture" did I?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that some non-experts may come to the website, figuring they may ask a question without searching answers online first. Some questions are *very* popular, so a quick search on the Internet is all it takes. When the non-expert returns to this Stacks Exchange, he is likely to ask questions based on his knowledge and any inconsistency he may have found in his knowledge.

Comment: @Anonymous Are you responding to my 4th bullet point and saying it's actually a good thing that we drive away newbies sometimes? (To clarify, what concerns me is when a brand new user is greeted by a scathing criticism, no welcome, no direction, and then we never see them again.)

Comment: @GoneQuiet Yes, but that wasn't the point of my post or my clarification. If I get too riled up about it I'll post a separate meta question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one is kind of funny, but also kind of frustrating. The top question on our site (by votes) is currently:

### [Does the Bible mention unicorns?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/106/529)

I wish our top question was something with a little more... class. Every time I go to our "votes" list I shake my head and long for the day when we have something more presentable at the top of that list.

(Don't get me wrong, I don't mind the question, I just wish it wasn't voted *the best question on the site!*)

Comment: The top voted posts on almost every site on the network are usually NOT something you'd want to promote. Frankly this is a social problem that gets worse with popularity and usage and doesn't have an easy solution. However in the case of that specific question, it was chosen to run in some promotional stuff so it got a lot more traffic than a normal question. Besides, this is a Stack Exchange operation, [are you unaware that Unicorns are a local meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/145951)?

Comment: @Caleb Hah... I did not know that!